# change xml layout to java code

Tags: android

Hi
can any one tell how we can change the xml layout to java code.
 I need to show the grid view inside the tab view . For that I need to implement these attributes in Java code rather than xml .Please reply

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

say you have the grid view accessed:

```
final GridView gw = [...];
```

For setting all the attributes above you should write:

```
// This line applies to a GridView that you've just created
gv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
// The next two lines are for a GridView that you already have displayed
gv.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
gv.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;

gv.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
gv.setVerticalSpacing(convertFromDp(10));
gv.setHorizontalSpacing(convertFromDp(10));
gv.setColumnWidth(convertFromDp(90));
gv.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
gv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

For setting the `LayoutParams`, you must choose between the two situations above.

Comment: could you please explain convertFromDp( ) also

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a new `GridView.LayoutParams` object and then pass it to `setLayoutParams(...)` or you can use the [methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android%3acolumnWidth) associated to the XML attributes to set each single layout parameter from Java.

Just create

`GridView.LayoutParams myParams = new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);`

Then you can use the methods provided by the `GridView.LayoutParams` via `myParams.someMethodName(...)`. You'll find the methods and supported parameters in the link above.

Then you'll pass the LayoutParams-object to your view via `myGridView.setLayoutParams(myParams);`